# paypal express checkout: 2 language

Tags: paypal

I have a 2 language website. I want to allow people to pay with paypal in their own language even without having a Paypal account. I use

1. `SOLUTIONTYPE = 'Sole';`
2. `LANDINGPAGE = 'Billing';`

to accomplish this. However when the form on Paypal is shown it is in Italian all the time because the country of destination is Italy.

I tried using LOCALECODE to GB to make the website be in english when on the english website but the form is still in Italian. Basically LOCALECODE does nothing. I can make the form be in English only by not setting:

```
'SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE' => 'IT',  
'SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME' => 'Italy',
```

But that is not ok because I need the country to be Italy.

I took the info from [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/).
Any reason why LOCALECODE is not working?

Note: I use curl to get the token from Paypal, not a form embedded in the page.

Comment: Could you try delete cookie in the browser and check call with LOCALCODE?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE and setting the version to 63.0 or up ?

Comment: Yes, i have $_paypalVersion = "82.0", i tried with both SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE and PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE, As soon I set it up it makes the language IT. It basically overwrites LOCALECODE = GB.

Comment: PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE is deprecated since v.63. [source](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)