# How to control the language of the paypal checkout page?

Tags: php, html, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using perstashop (an open source Eshop framework) paypal plugin to implement the paypal function.

Actually it is the PHP framework so it should be similar to other site implementation.

I would like to change the language of checkout page

And here is the code:

```
<form id="paypal_payment_form" action="{$base_dir_ssl}modules/paypal/express_checkout/payment.php" data-ajax="false" title="{l s='Pay with PayPal' mod='paypal'}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="express_checkout" value="{$PayPal_payment_type|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="current_shop_url" value="{$PayPal_current_page|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="{$PayPal_tracking_code|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" />
</form>
```

Someone said put the line

```
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="xx_XX">
```

in the form, I check the support locale code list and put it , unluckly it remain the same

So I wonder:

1) is this correct or I need to change elsewhere?

2) is the language in paypal changed in paypal panel instead of code? there is a default language setting, but how can I dynamic change base on the Eshop language?

3) can I control the language choice as well? My eshop has English, France and Germany but paypal checkout can only change between English and France, any idea ?

It is classic express checkout page.

Thanks for helping.

**Update:**

Found that the language is control by the delivery address. Then it means I can somehow change that

Comment: Are you currently in France or any other country, where french is the official language?

Comment: yes the cookies affect the language of the page but can I control it in program?

Comment: If you are logged into Paypal (or have a cookie set by paypal with regards to default locale), this will be automatic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I offered some time ago a bounty for the same thing. Nobody was able to help me: [paypal express checkout: 2 language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320199/paypal-express-checkout-2-language)

From what I figured the language depended on the country where the delivery was going to + if the person had an account with paypal and the language they previously used.

Comment: Are you looking which code I can change the language of the paypal page? After so many attempt I wonder whether can I change it through coding

Comment: Damn, I wrote a big reply but something happened to it. From what I saw you can set the language, however that will be ignored if 1) there is a paypal cookie. This makes a lot of sense. 2) if the delivery country is different than the country code you set up. For example when i set the language as EN but the delivery country was Italy then the paypal interface was set in Italian and not English like I asked it to do. This makes no sense but that is how it is.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've gotten the language code wrong because according to [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/), the code for France is `FR`, not `xx_XX`

```
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="FR"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems somewhere have override this parameter, as I added it in the form does not work, and the language can be change if I choose a different delivery address